# I want to write following query rails way

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
select DISTINCT firstname 
  from users u 
    inner join  members m 
      on m.user_id = u.id 
    inner join  member_roles m1 
      on m1.member_id = m.id 
    inner join roles r
      on r.id = m1.role_id  
  where r.name  = 'Project Coordinator'
```

this gives perfect result

I tried to write above query rails way
like

```
s = MemberRole.joins(:role).where("roles.name" => "Project Coordinator")

@u = User.select("users.firstname").includes(:members => s )
```

but seems doesnt work  any help??
thanks in advance

Comment: What associations have you defined between User, Member, MemberRole and Role models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.select("users.firstname").includes(:members => [{:member_roles => :role}]).where("roles.name" => "Project Coordinator")
```